# checkout older commit version from branch from bitbucket in Mac terminal command

Tags: git, bitbucket

Lets say I have branch name : `test`

Command  to clone master branch is `$git clone git@bitbucket.org:Xyz/Xyzprojectobjc.git`

To checkout code from the branch is :

```
$git clone -b test git@bitbucket.org:Xyz/Xyzprojectobjc.git
```

But I wanted to checkout or clone by code from branch name : test whose commitID is : `abcd12345`

how can I do that ?

I wanted to checkout that code and make changes in the code and push that code again.

Or I wanted to delete/revert all my last 4commit code from by `GIT BRANCH`

Below is the command which I tried but failed:

```
git reset --hard abcd12345 git@bitbucket.org:Xyz/Xyzprojectobjc.git

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Try 2 :

```
 git clone -b test git@bitbucket.org:Xyz/Xyzprojectobjc.git
```

-- this works and I am able to fetch the latest code from branch.but I wanted the code from previous commit.

Also if I wanted to checkout or clone the code from branch in Sourcetree. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i would go about it:
checkout the whole repo using -

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:Xyz/Xyzprojectobjc.git
```

then checkout the test branch locally using -

```
git checkout test
```

then hard reset the branch to ur sha (abcd12345) using -

```
git reset --hard abcd12345
```

this should do the trick, and the you can push your code to remote.

**NOTE: abcd12345 should be the sha of a commit on test branch itself**

Comment: for quick reply. Gitclone command work for me. But then when I try to use command for checkout test it gives me this error : fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git. . I guess we need to append git url behind this ? please help

Comment: There's a `cd` step after clone but before checkout - you have to do the rest from within the repository.